# How can I disable xml header generation in Spring Integration's xpath-splitter component

Tags: xml, xpath, spring-integration

My problem is that the `<xpath-splitter>` SI component generates fragments with xml-header which theoretically can be disabled by setting the `omit-xml-declaration` property of the underlying transformer to "yes"

How can I do that?
How can I set this property when I use `<xpath-slitter>`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

H-m. We can do that like:

```
TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
```

But we don't have an access to that `Transformer` from `XPathMessageSplitter`.

I think it one more good request to implement this one https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-2042.

Will it be difficult for you right now as a workaround to provide an input `payload` for `<xpath-splitter>` as `Node` instead of `String` and get result as `List<Node>`.

After that you can provide some custom `<transformer>` with the code:

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
StringResult result = new StringResult();
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(payload), result);
return result.toString();
```

And we'll take care about that JIRA issue in the nearest future.

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

The JIRA https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-2042 and (its related tickets) has been fixed in face of `output-properties` configuration option.